# understanding why htaccess change worked

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domains pointing to my server. htaccess is basically this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?parkeddomain\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1\.html$ https://www.newsite.net/page1/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page2\.html$ https://www.newsite.net/page2/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

I wanted to redirect the homepage as well. So I used these two rules in the list under that same RewriteCond:

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.newsite.net [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ https://www.newsite.net [L,R=301,NC]
```

When I add those two rules to the END of the list of RewriteRules under that condition (which specifies only the one domain) it was also forwarding my OTHER domain, apparently ignoring the RewriteCond altogether.

But by simply moving those two rules to the top of the list of RewriteRules now it is working as I want to it (eg not forwarding my other domain).

Why did this happen?

Thanks in advance. Just want to understand why this happened. The only other flags I used was "NE" on a couple of redirects that went to links with anchor links (eg https://www.newsite.net/#jumptoanchorlink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` only applies to the *next* `RewriteRule` in the file.  So if you have 4 `RewriteRule` following a `RewriteCond`, only the first one is impacted by it.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond
says

> One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive

You can combine `RewriteCond` with [AND] (implicit) or [OR].  But not `RewriteRule`.

In the same link they show an example:

```
RewriteCond  "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}"  "(iPhone|Blackberry|Android)"
RewriteRule  "^/$"                 "/homepage.mobile.html"  [L]

RewriteRule  "^/$"                 "/homepage.std.html"     [L]
```

If it is a phone, go to the mobile page, otherwise go to the standard page.  The `RewriteCond` only applies to the first one.  Otherwise, all users would always see the mobile page in that case.

FYI: If you split your domains in separate VirtualHost, you can manipulate one's configuration without impacting the other one.  And it does the split for you, so you do not even need the `RewiteCond` anymore.

Comment: For some reason I though all rewriterules until an empty line would adhere to the above rewritecond... and appreciate the VirtualHost advice. Thanks a lot for the thorough answer, man. Cheers.